# Filter MP3s by encoder type?

Tags: macos, itunes, mp3, metadata, file-filter

I'm on a Mac and use iTunes to manage my music collection. I'm in the process of weeding out the lower quality files that I have and would like to have only MP3s that have been encoded using the V0 setting of the LAME MP3 encoder. I tried using iTunes' smart playlist feature but as it only allows a less than rule and V0 is a variable amount, it catches valid V0 encoded files a lot of the time.

Is there any alternative program on Mac that I can just point to my iTunes folder and say, "show me all files that are not encoded with LAME V0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Dnuos](http://bitheap.org/dnuos/).

Download the latest tar.gz file from [here](http://bitheap.org/dnuos/files/). To install on Mac OS X, do the following:

```
tar zxvf dnuos-1.0.10.tar.gz
cd dnuos-1.0.10
sudo python setup.py install
```

After that, you should be able to run

```
dnuos ~/Music/
```

and get a list of all your tracks. You can use the output to search for your LAME V0 files.